# How to implement Callback interface using REST API with GET operation in Mule?

Tags: rest, callback, mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

How to implement Callback interface using REST API with GET operation in Mule? Any reference example with Mule is welcome

Comment: Can you please provide more details of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Usecase: When requesting for full data set, data will be push back to the given callback URL in the request.

And am doing it by creating a REST API which will internally call System API to fetch huge data load (Mule 4)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps with sample code (with a few assumptions stated at the end):

1. create RAML mapping in your project's `src/main/api`:

```
      #%RAML 0.8
      ---
      title: sample
      /YourServiceEndpoint
        get:
          responses:
            200:
              body:
                application/json:
```

2. Use APIKit Router in Mule to create a mapping in `src/main/app`. This uses `GET` as per the question (you can substitute with `POST` or any other REST action when writing integration tests for your use-case):

```
    <!-- /api/v1 is defined in the APIKit configuration -->
    <flow name="get:/api/v1/YourServiceEndPoint">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" ref="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <apikit:router config-ref="APIKitRouter" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
        <exception-strategy ref="Standard_Error_Responses" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>

        <!-- do all other stuff here; for example -->
        <when expression="#[payload.containsKey(&quot;resultSet1&quot;) &amp;&amp; payload.get(&quot;resultSet1&quot;).size() &gt; 0]">
           <set-payload value="#[payload.get(&quot;resultSet1&quot;).get(0)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
           <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        </when>
    </flow>
```

3. The above `connector-ref` requires your global configuration (most probably defined as `global-configuration.xml` in your project) to have a configuration snippet similar to one as follows:

```
    <https:connector name="HTTPS" enableCookies="true" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <https:tls-server path="${truststoreLocation}" storePassword="${truststorePassword}"/>
    </https:connector>
```

Assumptions:

1. APIKit Router requires Enterprise license from Mulesoft/Salesforce, otherwise this does not work.
2. The snippet paths assume use of Maven. Choose `Project > Mavenize` if your project does not support maven already.
3. This is just a suggestion and not relevant to the question. The use-case states "huge data load", which implies this should be handled differently by architecture -- you should probably use SFTP instead of HTTP/HTTPS API.

Helpful note(s):

1. There are additional samples within the application's Help menu which demonstrate the use of SOAP, `Callable` interface, etc. That will allow you to move forward.